# Can we sort Recogntion Tab in Chatter Profile? Can it be re-named?

Tags: work.com

Team,

Looking for some advise on Recognition Tab in Salesforce for Chatter Profile. I guess the data for the tab comes from "Badges Received" Object.

Wondering if the tab can be re-named and the data in Recognition tab can be sorted.

Regards,
Manoj.